# Toggle boolean on state in react

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I feel like I've done it correctly but the state is not being toggled. My state doesn't change to true when the checkbox is checked.

```
export default class Room extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           isChecked: false
        };

        this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this);
    }

 toggleChecked() {
        this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked });
    }

 selectAllRooms(){
        if(this.state.isChecked === true){
           //do smth; 
        }else{
           //do smth;
    }

render() {
    return (
       <Modal.Footer>
            <Checkbox onChange={this.toggleChecked}> Select All Rooms </Checkbox>
       <Modal.Footer> 
  )
 }
)
```

Comment: How did you verify this hypothesis that state did not change?

Comment: where you called this function selectAllRooms() ???

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings by looking at React Dev tools

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I haven't called `selectAllRooms()`. I'd like to call it when the state of `isChecked` changes to true but I can't get it to do this first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react state updates may be asynchronous, if you wish to access the previous values you should do it in the following manner:

```
toggleChecked() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isChecked: !prevState.isChecked }));
}
```

When you pass in a function to the setState method the first argument makes reference to the previous state and the second the previous props.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to have worked either. I even changed by checkbox to just be a `<Button onClick={this.toggleChecked}> Select All Rooms </Button>` and this still doesn't toggle the value of `isChecked: false` in the state.

Comment: It should work but it doesn't update right away, if you need to access the new state as soon as it changes, you can pass a callback function to the setState method or use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook.